# Trying to clarify my argument in an automata proof

Tags: soft-question, automata, advice

**The question:**

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet and $L\subseteq \Sigma^*$ be a non-empty language over that alphabet.  Prove that if $L=L^2$ then $e \in L$ (where $e$ represents the empty string).

**My Solution Sketch:**

I first assume $L = L^2$. That is, every element in $L$ is also in $L^2$ and vice versa.

Because $e$ concatenated with itself ($ee$) is just $e$, then the only way for $L = L^2$ to hold is if $e \in L$. Otherwise, not every element in $L$ would be in $L^2$ and vice versa.

**My concern:**

It's only a sketch of a proof but I feel like it's very handwavy and not very rigorous. It is my first foray into automata so if anyone could provide some tips on how to formalize this argument and add more rigor to it, it would be very appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this proof works.  What goes wrong if $e \not\in L$?

Comment: I would just say, suppose the shortest string in $L$ has length $\ell$.  Then the shortest string in $L^2$ has length $2\ell$.  If $L^2=L$, then $2\ell=\ell$, or $\ell=0$; hence $e\in L$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx You could make that last comment an answer.

Comment: @saulspatz It's too short :).

Comment: @mjqxxxx: It’s a good answer, and it would get the question off the unanswered list. If you really want to add some substance, you could preface it by giving a little intuition: every $x\in L$ must have the form $yz$ for some $y,z\in L$, and if $e\notin L$, then $|y|<|x|$, so for each $x\in L$ there would be a shorter $y\in L$, and that’s pretty clearly impossible. Yours is then simply a nicer way to make essentially this argument.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks for your comment! (Same to mjqxxx, although I can't tag 2 people at once). It seems after asking this question, I wrote a proof by contradiction similar to yours, but it was still less rigorous, so it helps a lot ))

Comment: @a6623: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is wrong. Indeed, if $L = \emptyset$, then $L = L^2$, but $L$ does not contain the empty word.
The correct statement should assume that $L$ is nonempty.